# getting all values from select tag not only the selected ones using flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to display all itms and not onlythe selected items .In fact with this code i only get the selected items but i nedd all the items
    The code:

```
 from flask import Flask,render_template,request
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/result",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
 multiselect = request.form.getlist('select1[]')
 multiselect
 print(multiselect)
 return render_template('index.html')
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the html:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('result') }}">
    <div class="select_1">
        <select id="select1" name="select1[]" multiple="multiple" >
            <option value="costumor">costumor</option>
            <option value="shipto">shipto</option>
            <option value="bu">bu</option>
            <option value="reference_client">reference_client</option>
            <option value="designation">designation</option>
            <option value="categorie">categorie</option>
            <option value="reference_product">reference_product</option>
            <option value="fournisseur">fournisseur</option>
            <option value="reference_fournisseur">reference_fournisseur</option>
            <option value="Qtes">Qtes</option>
            <option value="date">date</option>

        </select>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>    
</form>
```

Comment: Do not use `[]`. Try with `request.form.getlist('slect1')`

Comment: I tried it but it give a blank list

Comment: Do you want to get the selected items or All the options values ?

Comment: I want to get all the options values The code display only when i select items

Comment: No. Only selected items will pass into Flask form. You may need to find other ways to get the options. Why not try with javascript form submit?>

Comment: thank you i wil try with javascript